# How to run Flutter app styled as iOS on Android

Tags: flutter

I have some widgets in my Flutter app which are styled differently between Android and iOS (where I have done this, I always used Theme.of(context).platform).

I'm using an old MacBook Air to build my iOS apps and did some screenshots using it, but they are too low res, so I want to redo these on my PC using an Android emulator.

I can adjust a few things and run the app styled as iOS on the Android emulator, but rather than adjusting my code, is there a command line parameter I can pass to tell it to run as an iOS device?

I just want the app to look like it would as if it is running on an iOS device for the purposes of taking some screenshots.

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-io/do-flutter-apps-dream-of-platform-aware-widgets-7d7ed7b4624d might interest you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
MaterialApp(theme: ThemeData(platform: TargetPlatform.iOS),
```

or use Cupertino widgets https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/widgets/cupertino